# An amorphous connect wall

Tags: connect-wall

The set of sixteen items below can be partitioned. Each partition is of four items that have something in common. I invite you to figure out the partitions and commonalities. You'll find that the four commonalities are of the same type in some sense; and that, taken together, they clue an eight-letter word.

BULL, COME, DICK, KO, LEE, ME, MULL, NIT, RE-ROBE, RICH, RUBBLE, SEW, SHELLS, STIR, TELL, WEIGH

Hint (added later):

> RE would work instead of RE-ROBE (and would be a more appropriate word for this puzzle) were it not for the fact that it's also a musical note.  I included RE-ROBE because it's easy and in my hope that people use it to start solving the puzzle.

Another hint (added even later):

> I don't know why I included NIT rather than KNIT.  It makes no difference whatsoever.

Another hint (added even later):

> LEE and TELL are in the same partition.

Another hint (mentioned a little while ago in the comments on the question):

> [Bubbler](/users/71652/bubbler) asked me whether the *KO* on the board is "ko" or "K.O." and I replied that it's the former and that that question is important.

Another hint (mentioned a little while ago in the comments on [an answer](/a/104547)):

> The fact that none of the words contain the letter *A* is just by chance.
>
> Well… there may actually be some sort of linguistic connection between the wall's rules and the absence of an *A*. Like, maybe it's easier to find non-*A* words to fit the wall's rules than to find *A* words to fit them. But knowing that is *probably* not going to help you.

Another hint (added even later):

> One European and one African country are represented here by name.

Another hint (added even later):

> Also, a big city in East Anglia is represented by name.

Comment: Is KO "Ko" or "K.O."?

Comment: My observations so far: rot13(Bayl OHYY, ZHYY, GRYY, FURYYF pbagnva qbhoyr Y. Bayl QVPX, AVG, EVPU, FGVE pbagnva na V orgjrra gjb pbafbanagf (nyfb jbexf jvgu XAVG). Bayl ER-EBOR, EHOOYR, EVPU, FGVE pbagnva na E. Bayl PBZR, ZHYY, FGVE, EHOOYR pbagnva n fubeg "hu"-fbhaq. Bayl OHYY, ZHYY, GRYY, EHOOYR raq jvgu na Y-fbhaq. Bayl PBZR, YRR, EHOOYR, JRVTU pbagnva rknpgyl gjb ibjry yrggref. Bayl FURYYF, FGVE, EHOOYR, ER-EBOR pbagnva rknpgyl guerr pbafbanag fbhaqf.)

Comment: My observations over the last couple of days potential groups rot 13 Cnvef jvgu Hc ng gur raq gb znxr n cuenfr (Pbzr, jrvtu, fgve, frj), Unf n qbhoyr pbafbanag sbe 3eq naq 4gu yrggref (gryy, ehooyr, zhyy, ohyy) Eulzrf jvgu zhfvpny abgrf (zr,xb,frj, jrvtu) V xabj yrr pna svg urer gbb.

Comment: Two more: rot13(YRR ZR ER-EBOR JRVTU (svefg ibjry fbhaq vf ybat, pbagnvavat na /v/); XB YRR ZR (X)AVG (vf n jbeq jura erirefrq))

Comment: "FIFTEENTH • Wrong! All answers are wrong!" — _The Westing Game_ (which, incidentally, if you haven't read, you should. Not that it'll help with this puzzle: it's just a good-quality kids' book)

Comment: @Bubbler https://en.wiktionary.org/?oldid=60354892#English (and that's an important question)

Comment: @msh210 Thanks, I was asking because I was aware of the Go terminology.

Comment: The third hint gives at least two possibilities for that group: rot13(YRR GRYY EHOOYR FURYYF jurer R naq Y ner nqwnprag, be OHYY YRR GRYY ZHYY juvpu raq va gur cnggrea KLL). Also I'm still having a feeling that the first vowel sounds of KO and RE/RE-ROBE are important.

Comment: Gargh, I think I am VERY close to nailing this down good and proper but the exact groupings are eluding me... (kinda important in a connect-wall puzzle, I know...) If I'm right, there is something VERY important to note about the whole word set chosen that has not yet been mentioned in comments. (Just going to leave that cryptically there for now...)

Comment: Hmmm... I've had two further theories that fit with all of your given clues except the REROBE part of the first, which I'm still looking to satisfy. For the one I feel is the closest match I can't put my finger on the last group (which would contain rot13(EREBOR, FGVE, AVG naq XB) - all assuming I'm on the *rite* track now...) - would you advise I keep looking at those 4 words or turn my attention elsewhere?

Comment: I think I might be along the same lines as you!

Comment: @Stiv three of those four are in the same foursome. Perhaps you have the right idea and  got one item misplaced (possibly due to my own fault) or perhaps it's the wrong idea altogether: I don't have enough info to guess at that intelligently at this point.

Comment: So far the two groups I have for sure are (weigh,dick,rich,mull) (lee,tell,me,sew)

Comment: Not sure about shells I am sure that is the African country you are talking about but I just can't tie it in with the other clues...

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker, that first foursome is correct. (The other has three correct.) But if you know what to do for "shells" then you'll know what else is in its foursome….

Answer (score 4, accepted):

8 letter word:

> Carreras thanks to JS1 for this

Group 1

> Prefix Ho__+ word (LEE, TELL, COME, ME) makes Holy, Hotel, Hokum, Homey

Group 2

> Prefix Nor__+ word (WEIGH, DICK, RICH, MULL) makes Norway, Nordic, Norwich, Normal

Group 3

> Prefix Sey__+ word (SHELLS, SEW, BULL, KO) Seychelles, Say-So , Sable, Seiko

Group 4

> Prefix Te + word (RE-ROBE, RUBBLE, STIR, NIT) Terry-Robe, Terrible, Tester, Tenet

> If you take the syllables you can spell Jose Tenor which hints at Jose Carreras.

Comment: Very close! Group 2 is right and note how group 1 is rot13(qrsvarq fvzvyneyl gb tebhc 2... lbh zvtug pbafvqre pbagvahvat nybat gur fnzr yvarf. Bu, naq qb lbh ernyyl cebabhapr ubeevoyr jvgu gur fnzr ibjry nf gur bgure ub- jbeqf?)

Comment: This is very similar to what I was working on in comments above. My Group 3 however was rot13(FNL: FURYYF (FRLPURYYRF), OHYY (FNOYR), FRJ (FNL-FB), ZR (FNZRL) juvyr V unq PBZR va gur UB tebhc (UBXHZ))

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: The four groups are defined correctly and have the correct elements in them — well done! — but that's not the eight-letter word I was thinking of.  (Ignore the puzzle title: there's no real clue there.)

Comment: No idea where to look, can you hint?

Comment: This is the best I have got.

Comment: Msh I changed the answer a while back please take a look.

Comment: Yeah, I saw. Still not the eight-letter word I was thinking of. I'll give some time before hinting further.

Comment: Is this it?????

Comment: No, that's not it.  I'll give some time before hinting further.

Comment: Rot13: Pbhyq gur nafjre or Pneerenf orpnhfr gur sbhe pngrtbevrf gbtrgure orpbzr "Grabe Wbfr"?

Comment: Give @JS1 a cigar!

Comment: Ah nice one!!!!

Comment: I thought of Jose tenor but I thought it was a lot of rubbish, should have googled it!

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, there's something very important to notice about the word set in this puzzle:

> *None of the words contain the letter 'A'!*

I believe this is a deliberate clue and is supposed to hint at:

> The need to manipulate these words using the letter A to make new words. This is backed up by use of the word 'A-MORPHOUS' in the title, which suggests in a punny way that we need to *morph* (i.e. 'change the form of') the words in this puzzle using the letter 'A' in all of our transformations.

The wall can then be resolved as follows:

> **Group 1: Can add an 'A' to make a new word**
>  BULL --> [BULL**A**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bulla)
>  LEE --> [**A**LEE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alee)
>  STIR --> **A**STIR/S**A**TIR/ST**A**IR
>  WEIGH --> [**A**WEIGH](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aweigh)
>
>  **Group 2: Can change the last letter to an 'A' to make a new word**
>  COME --> COM**A**
>  KO --> [K**A**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ka)
>  ME --> M**A**
>  SEW --> SE**A**
>
>  **Group 3: Change a letter *other than the last* to an 'A' to make a new word**
>  REROBE --> **A**EROBE
>  RUBBLE --> R**A**BBLE
>  SHELLS --> [SHE**A**LS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sheal)
>  TELL --> T**A**LL
>
>  **Group 4: Change a letter to an 'A' *and reverse the letter order* to make a new word**
>  DICK --> DIC**A** --> **ACID**
>  MULL --> MUL**A** --> [**ALUM**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alum)
>  NIT --> N**A**T --> **TAN**
>  RICH --> RI**A**H --> **HAIR**

While I can't immediately spot a punny 8-letter word that sums this up, a suitable one based on earlier observations about the title might be:

> **MORPHING** - although I am open to better suggestions!

Comment: Just noticed after posting that this doesn't satisfy the third hint, so I must have *something* in the wrong group, but so much of this fits (including the first two hints) that I feel this must be incredibly close to the bullseye...! :)

Comment: If this was the intended answer, I would be disappointed.

Comment: According to [QAT](https://www.quinapalus.com/qat.html), you can put rot13(gryy (gryn) naq yrr (yrn) vagb tebhc 2, zbir frj (fnj) gb tebhc 3, naq zbir xb (xbn) gb tebhc 1).

Comment: This is most ingenious. It doesn't seem to explain the observation in hint 1 that RE-ROBE could have been RE instead _if RE hadn't been the name of a musical note_.

Comment: +1. As noted, this doesn't match a couple of the hints — and it's not my intended answer. Perhaps it's time for a stronger hint.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thanks - my assumption there was that was to steer us *away* from trying to form a group of 4 musical note homophones out of RE, ME, SEW and (insert another one here). Never mind though - back to the drawing board!

Comment: @msh210 This is happening to me a lot this week...! Is the initial observation at all important or just another freak coincidence?!

Comment: @Stiv, the latter.

Comment: @msh210 WHAAAAA??! Somebody really needs to invent an emoji for this scenario...

Answer (score -1):

First step is to make a wall.  The words are in alphabetical order in the puzzle, and I am assuming they must be grouped an re-ordered.

> 3 or less
>  clue: "I don't know why I included NIT rather than KNIT"
>  answer: 3 rather than 4 letters, number of letters is important?
>  KO LEE ME NIT

> have LL
>  BULL MULL SHELLS TELL

> verbs that involve an object
>  RE-ROBE STIR SEW WEIGH

> remainder
>  COME DICK RICH RUBBLE

Which creates a wall like - alphabetical

```
 BULL     MULL    SHELLS   TELL     
 COME     DICK    RICH     RUBBLE
 KO       LEE     ME       NIT   
 RE-ROBE  STIR    SEW      WEIGH
```

Or perhaps grouped vertically

```
 BULL     COME    KO       RE-ROBE
 MULL     DICK    LEE      STIR
 SHELLS   RICH    ME       SEW
 TELL     RUBBLE  NIT      WEIGH
```

But the order of the elements in the wall is a mystery to me. Assuming the elements in the 4 groups are related to each other, than what order are the 4 groups to each other?

Comment: I specifically said NIT vs. KNIT makes no difference; so your first group can't be. KNIT and SHELLS also are verbs involving objects. And "the rest" is not generally considered a valid group in a connect wall.

Comment: But you also said you chose NIT over KNIT.  But if that's not the case, then it's got to be a phonetic clue.

Comment: "The words are in alphabetical order in the puzzle, and I am assuming they must be grouped an re-ordered." No need to assume. The puzzle says to group them. It doesn't say to order them, and indeed there's no need (or clued criterion by which) to.